# How to alias git commands your .bash_aliases file

Tags: git, unix, git-bash

I am trying to set up git aliases in my .bash_alias file. I know you can set up aliases in your .gitconfig file but that would add 4 extra key strokes to the alias ("git "). I have a few aliases that work in .gitconfig but I can't get them to work in .bash_aliases.

```
alias glg='log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h\\ %ad%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --date=short'
alias gll='log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --numstat'
alias gld='log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h\\ %C(green)%ad%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --date=short --graph'
alias gls='log --pretty=format:"%C(green)%h\\ %C(yellow)[%ad]%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --date=relative'
alias gb="!git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate' --format='%(authordate)%09%(objectname:short)%09%(refname)' refs/heads | sed -e 's-refs/heads/--'"
```

can anyone tell me what I have to do to get this working?

Comment: You need to create a `~/.bash_profile` in your home path and add your aliases there for an interactive shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the leading "git"!  Also, not sure why you have the backslashes.  Try:

```
alias glg='git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %ad%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --date=short'
alias gll='git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --numstat'
alias gld='git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(green)%ad%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --date=short --graph'
alias gls='git log --pretty=format:"%C(green)%h %C(yellow)[%ad]%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --date=relative'
alias gb="git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate' --format='%(authordate)%09%(objectname:short)%09%(refname)' refs/heads | sed -e 's-refs/heads/--'"
```

But really, there's no need to use aliases, and these would be better written as functions.  That is:

```
glg() { git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %ad%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --date=short; }
gll() { git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --numstat; }
gld() { git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(green)%ad%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --date=short --graph; }
gls() { git log --pretty=format:"%C(green)%h %C(yellow)[%ad]%Cred%d %Creset%s%Cblue [%cn]" --decorate --date=relative; }
gb() { git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate' --format='%(authordate)%09%(objectname:short)%09%(refname)' refs/heads | sed -e 's-refs/heads/--'; }
```

Comment: Thanks that was such a stupid oversight. I feel embarrassed.